# Frustrated - filled in FEDEX details in the Admin (1.9.1) and got a Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: fedex

I can't believe in this day and age things have to be so difficult. I installed a fresh Magento install - 1.9.1. - I just needed 2 things - a responsive theme and a calendar. I installed a 100% responsive theme, then bought (and installed) a calendar and the calendar is showing really really bad (like you can't even tell what month you are in and so on...)

Anyways, I want to ask all of you smart people here this:

I called Fedex, got all the settings to **fill in on the Fedex Shipping option in the Admin panel** and then - *the front end stopped working!* It gives the following Error:

**Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/clothes/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php on line 134**

I tried to seach for this Error on the web but there are such complicated answers.

Can someone please explain in simple terms what I need to do to fix this?

Thank you very much,

Allysin

Answer (score 2):

`SoapClient` is a PHP class that the FedEx module uses to communicate with the FedEx systems.

The most common cause of the error you're getting (class `SoapClient` not found) is that the PHP SoapClient extension is not enabled. This is a setting within your `php.ini` file. If you're not comfortable checking your `php.ini` file (or simply do not have access to it), ask your server hosting provider to enable the SoapClient PHP extension.